# Submitting GetUserOofSettings and SetUserOofSettings request

Tags: php, php-ews

Does anyone have any code about both getting and setting users OOF messages using [Garethp/php-ews](https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews) library by any chance?

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563465(v=exchg.140))

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa493825(v=exchg.140))

I have tried the following

```
use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;
use garethp\ews\API\Enumeration\DistinguishedFolderIdNameType;
use garethp\ews\API\Enumeration\UserConfigurationPropertyType;
use garethp\ews\API\Enumeration\GetUserOofSettingsRequestType;

$email = 'me@mycompany.com';

$host = 'myexchserver'; $username = 'myusername'; $password = 'mypassword';

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword($host,$username,$password,["version" => 'Exchange2010_SP1', 'impersonation' => $email]);
$response = $api->getClient()->GetUserOofSettingsRequest(['Address' => 'someuser@mycompany.com']);
```

But get the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("GetUserOofSettingsRequest") is not a valid method for this service in /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/NTLMSoapClient.php:119 Stack trace: #0 /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/NTLMSoapClient.php(119): SoapClient->__call() #1 /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/ExchangeWebServices/MiddlewareFactory.php(18): garethp\ews\API\NTLMSoapClient->__call() #2 /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/ExchangeWebServices.php(510): garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices\{closure}() #3 /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/ExchangeWebServices/MiddlewareFactory.php(32): garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->garethp\ews\API\{closure}() #4 /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/ExchangeWebServices.php(510): garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices\{closure}() #5 /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/ExchangeWebServices/MiddlewareFactory.php(48): garethp\ews\API\ExchangeWebServices->garethp\ew in /Scripts/vendor/garethp/php-ews/src/API/NTLMSoapClient.php on line 119
```

Thanks